# Visual studio 2017 net framework 4.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Используя русскую VS 2017 переключаясь на целевую платформу в проекте 4.5 все подсказки в студии становятся на англ. яз. а некоторые и вовсе пропадают (см скриншот) но при включение любой другой версии все подсказки становятся на русском, переустановить фраемворк не дает win10.
[image: 4.5]

[image: 4.5]

[image: 4.5.1]

Comment: Попробуйте установить это: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=30667

Comment: Сведения

Майкрософт .NET Framework 4.5 уже является частью этой операционной системы. Установка распространяемого компонента .NET Framework 4.5 не требуется.

На этом компьютере уже установлена та же или более новая версия .NET Framework 4.5 RUS Языковой пакет.

Comment: Тривиальный вопрос,важны ли подсказки на Русском языке? По сути вопроса, создайте новый проект изначально с версией NET 4.5, и проверьте поведение. Есть предположение что это кэш от Intelisense.

Comment: Ну нужны ли они или нет, работать они все же должны... По поводу начальной платформы данный проект создан под 4.5 изначально для демонстрации проблемы...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37591972/6808809